# Is there a meaningful usage of the lazy "??" in regex?

Tags: regex, computer-science, pcre

Acoording to the laziness of quantifiers they want to match as least as possible. In my eyes the quantifier `??` makes no sense. Because there is always the option not to match the quantified part if the previuos succeded. Therefore it is redundant.

e.g. `apples??`

will always match `apple` and `apples` only on the `apple` part without the `s` on the end

Answer (score 2):

Here is a case where `?` and `??` produce different results.

Text to match: `a`

With `a?`, there will be 2 matches - `"a"` and `""`.

With `a??`, there will be 3 matches - `""`, `"a"` and `""`. It also matched the empty string at the start, because it tries to match as little as possible.

Another reason for `??` to exist is that all other quantifiers have a lazy counterpart. It makes sense for `?`, also a quantifier, to have a lazy counterpart.

Comment: Ok, but it is really in some kind useful? It produces different results. the word `apples` is matched different to. But does `??` gives any power to the expression? Can i not just dont write the `??` ?

Comment: @DIBits Doesn't the dupe target answer your question? If not, tell me where you are still confused and I can reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

Another use for `??` is to make your pattern more efficient. The lazyness of `??` will mean that it'll attempt to *not* match the previous token initially, and will attempt to match the rest of the pattern first. If the rest of the pattern is *expensive*, the use of a lazy `?` vs a greedy `?` can be a useful tweak to make. For a contrived example, if the string is

```
appleszzzzz
```

and the pattern is (greedy):

```
apples?(?:.){6}$
```

The engine will first attempt to match the `s`, because it's greedy. Then, it'll repeat the `.` group 6 times, try to match the end of the string, which will fail. Then it'll backtrack, giving up the `s` it matched before, repeat the 6 characters followed by `$`, and succeed.

If the `?` was lazy, the backtracking wouldn't be necessary, because the `s` would *not* be matched initially. See

https://regex101.com/r/I6u6F2/2

for an example - remove the lazy part of the `??` and you'll see that the number of steps required jumps from 21 to 33. The more expensive the rest of the pattern is, the more important the consideration of this sort of thing.